# Mathematical equation in vba

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have mathematical equation which I am performing in sheet **"`Accrued Expenses`"** on **`Range("E7")`**. The formula is intend to **loop**  till the **lastrow in column C** The two key sheets are **"Start page"** and **"Accrued Expenses"** .

**The problem** is that **I am not able to get into VBA code**. It works using the Excel macro recorder, but it wont be efficient for maintenance. My equation and code below.

```
=('Accrued Expenses'!C7*'Start page'!$F$5)/'Start page'!$F$13*'Accrued Expenses'!D7
```

In **Excel recorder code** and with a loop:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Calculating_Accruedexpense()
    Sheets("Accrued Expenses").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("E7").Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.row = LastRow + 1
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=('Accrued Expenses'!RC[-2]*'Start page'!R5C6)/'Start page'!R13C6*'Accrued Expenses'!RC[-1]"
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Excel Recorder line:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=('Accrued Expenses'!RC[-2]*'Start page'!R5C6)/'Start page'!R13C6*'Accrued Expenses'!RC[-1]"
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the same formula into every cell you loop over? Or do you want the range references in the formula to change for each cell in the loop?

Comment: @Alexp In the equation where there is absolute reference ($) those reference do not change. However all other references in the formula Will  change for each cell in the loop.

Comment: Do you want the actual formula in the cell or just the result?

Comment: See below for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Calculating_AccruedExpense()
    Dim lastRow As Long, cl As Range

    lastRow = Worksheets("Accrued Expenses").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cl In Range("E7:E" & lastRow)
        If IsEmpty(cl) Then
            cl = (cl.Offset(0, -1) * Worksheets("Start page").Range("F5")) / Worksheets("Start page").Range("F13") * cl.Offset(0, -2)
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```